# Spring data mongoDB saving incomplete java Bitset Object

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I am working in mongoDB in java. I want to save java Bitset Object in db and since only BSON native types can be converted from their Java counterparts, I have to use mapper libs.

I used Mongo Morphia Mapper and save Bitset object successfully. But I require to do same using Spring Data MongoDB libs. But using spring libs Bitset Object is not saved and there is no error while saving. And when i retrieve same Object i get empty biset object.  Below is how data was saved in mongo database using Morphia and Spring respectively :

**Morphia**

1. { "_id" : "testid", "name" : "spring", "bit" : **{ "words" : [ NumberLong(132) ], "wordsInUse" : 1, "sizeIsSticky" : true }** }

**Spring**

1. { "_id" : "testid", "name" : "spring", "bit" : **{ "words" : [ NumberLong(132) ] }** }

By complaring the two I noticed that Biset information using spring is not saved completely(bold part). This might be reason for empty Bitset Object. I am using 'spring-data-mongodb-1.0.0.M4.jar' for saving. Please can anyone tell where I am wrong. I would appreciate your help.

Thanks

Shubhra

---

@Asya Kamsky

Below is code i am using to save using spring :

```
BitSet b = new BitSet(10);  
b.set(2);  
b.set(7);

MyClass myclass = new MyClass("testid","spring",b);

ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringMongoConfig.class); 

MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations)ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate"); 

mongoOperation.save(myclass);
```

Comment: Could you provide sample snippets of your code for Spring showing how you are saving the object?

Comment: Is there any solution? I would appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: It looks to me like bit _was_ set with Spring, words was saved as subdocument called "bit" (bolded above).  Is it possible you are fetching the stored data incorrectly?  By the way, you can both edit your original post to add more information and/or add comments the way I'm doing.  Answers (below) are reserved for answers to your original question, not answers to comments.

Comment: Thanks Asya. This is the way I am fetching the data  List<BitSet> list = mongoOperations.findAll(MyClass.class); and if I am not wrong this is correct method.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see this behavior is that the Spring Data Mapping subsystem considers transient fields as not to be persisted (the relevant code is in `AbstractPersistenProperty.isTransient()`). I've filed a [JIRA issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATACMNS-180) and implemented and deployed a fix against the [1.3.x](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-commons/commit/9c42393a5141ff7c0485749e7cadb735a3bd268a) and [1.4.x](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-commons/commit/031129e46199fa8ce3c012a5185b455dfd6933eb) branches of Spring Data Commons. You can already use that by referring to the snapshot versions of either branch.